# Excel "Insert shapes" Color change based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Anyone knows how to Change the color of Shapes("Insert-> Shapes") based on the value of a cell. i could do this with the help of macro. but i now need the same to be done without the help of macro.

Kindly share the formula if anyone can do this.

thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without a macro. There is no "conditional formatting" for shapes.

Comment: It is - without macro - possible to show the picture of a named Excel range in a ActiveX image control. If the range of this named range depends on a cell value, so depending of the cell value multiple ranges could be shown, and in those ranges are shapes placed...

Comment: hello  Axel Richter thanks for the response. could you please explain me this with a example. It would be a great help for me and i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to show the picture of a named range in a ActiveX image control:

1. Open Excel with a empty Worksheet Sheet1.
2. Write 0 in A1.
3. Create a named range using the Name Manager http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx#BMmanage_names_by_using_the_name_manage

to do so:

- open Name Manager
- click New
- Name= Image
- Refers To= `=INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,Sheet1!$A$1*4+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,Sheet1!$A$1*4+4)`
- OK
- close Name Manager

now:

1. Take a ActiveX Image Control from Developer tab
   (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/show-the-developer-tab-HA101819080.aspx)
   Controls and put it in the Worksheet.
2. Overwrite the formula `=EMBED(...)` in the formula bar with `=Image`
   (the name of  the named range). Now, if you change the value in `Sheet1!A1`,
   you should see the cells `E[n]:E[m]` with `n=A1*4+1` and `m=A1*4+4` as
   picture in the Image Control. Try it by putting values in `E1:E20`
   and change `A1`.
3. Now, if you place different shapes over `E1:E4, E5:E8, E9:E12,...` you
   see them in the Image Control by changing the value in `A1`.

   ---

**Edit April 2019:**

This works using `Excel 2007`. It does not work in later `Excel versions` because the ActiveX Image control does not more accept cell ranges as source.

Just tested in `Excel 365`:

First do the same steps as above but then in last step

now:

1. Copy four cells of one column (`A1:A4` for example) into the clipboard. It is not important from where the cells are coming.
2. In the sheet where the image shall appear do `Home -> Paste -> Linked Picture`. A picture showing the copied cells is pasted. And the formula bar shows the formula `=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4` for example.
3. Overwrite the formula in the formula bar with `=Image` (the name of the named range). Now, if you change the value in `Sheet1!A1`, you should see the cells `E[n]:E[m]` with `n=A1*4+1` and `m=A1*4+4` as picture in the pasted picture. Try it by putting values in `E1:E20` and change `A1`.
4. Now, if you place different shapes over `E1:E4, E5:E8, E9:E12,...` you see them in the pasted picture by changing the value in `A1`.

Comment: I appreciate that this is an old thread, but on step 2, when changing =EMBED(...) to =Image, it comes back with an error 'Reference isn't valid'. any ideas why this might be, please?

Comment: This works using `Excel 2007`. It does not work in later `Excel versions` because the ActiveX Image control does not more accept cell ranges as source.

Comment: @Joe J: Found a solution using `Excel 365`. See my supplements.